# jquery menu bar floating on the top

Tags: jquery, menu

I'm trying to make a menu bar float constantly at the top of the browser, so when one scroll down the page the menu bar remains at the top. I got the script, but I am not able  to integrate that.

Please help me in this, how could I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your key is to use `position: fixed`:

```
div#menu {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">Buttons and stuff goes here.</div>
```

In the above example I used `width:100%` to stretch the menu over the entire width of the page. You can use the top, left, right and bottom properties to position the menu.